# Reading JSON on Android, No Output

Tags: java, android, json

This is my JSON data.

```
{"JSONDATA":[{"key":0,"value":"--Any--"},{"key":61,"value":"Accounting"},{"key":81,"value":"Aerospace & Defense"},{"key":72,"value":"Automotive"},{"key":83,"value":"Banking"},{"key":84,"value":"Biotech"},{"key":85,"value":"Construction"},{"key":86,"value":"Customer Service"},{"key":87,"value":"Education"},{"key":82,"value":"Energy"},{"key":70,"value":"Finance"},{"key":193,"value":"Government"},{"key":194,"value":"Healthcare"},{"key":71,"value":"Insurance"},{"key":73,"value":"Legal"},{"key":62,"value":"Management"},{"key":63,"value":"Manufacturing"},{"key":64,"value":"Marketing\/Advertising"},{"key":77,"value":"Media - Journalism"},{"key":74,"value":"Pharmaceutical"},{"key":75,"value":"Real Estate"},{"key":76,"value":"Research"},{"key":65,"value":"Restaurant"},{"key":66,"value":"Retail"},{"key":67,"value":"Sales"},{"key":78,"value":"Science"},{"key":68,"value":"Telecommunications"},{"key":79,"value":"Training"},{"key":69,"value":"Transportation"},{"key":80,"value":"Utilities"}]}
```

I want to decode it on my Android App,  This is the code i have used., But i don't get anything on my output. No errors too.

```
JSONObject jObject= new JSONObject();
JSONArray menuObject = new JSONArray(jObject.getString("JSONDATA"));
String app;
for (int i = 0; i<menuObject.length(); i++) {
{
 app=menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("value").toString();
 a.append(app); // a is my TextView
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its wrong:

```
JSONArray menuObject = new JSONArray(jObject.getString("JSONDATA"));
```

Try:

```
JSONObject jObject= new JSONObject(yourJSONString);
JSONArray menuObject = jObject.getJSONArray("JSONDATA");
```

**Keep one thing in mind:**
Create a JSON Object with JSON String you want to parse and then you can fetch String/JSON Object or JSON Array from the created JSON Object.

Answer (score 4):

First off, you're not initializing your `jObject` with anything.

```
//pass in string
JSONObject jObject= new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

`JSONObject`s need something to parse, otherwise (the way you have it now) they initialize with no data, which isn't very helpful.

Secondly, you're using `getString` when you really want an array:

```
JSONArray menuObject = jObject.getJSONArray("JSONDATA");
```

`getString` is designed to return a piece of *string data* from a JSON object. `"JSONDATA"` holds an *array*, so we need to choose the correct type to retrieve.

Thirdly, you have a redundant `toString()`, as `getString` already returns a `String`:

```
app=menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your json response in a String

```
String jsonResponse="YOUR JSON RESPONSE STRING";
```

//Pass the string as below

```
JSONObject jObject= new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
JSONArray menuObject = jObject.getJSONArray("JSONDATA"));
String app;
for (int i = 0; i<menuObject.length(); i++) {
{
 app=menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("value").toString();
 a.append(app); // a is my TextView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the appropiate getters and setters in `JSONObject` and `JSONArray`, and your "JSONDATA" entry is not a string. Do something like this:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
JSONArray menuArray = jObject.getJSONArray("JSONDATA");
for (int i = 0; i < menuArray.length(); i++) {
    String app = menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("value");
    a.append(app); // a is my TextView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for parse your json string.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(youtString);
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("JSONDATA");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject c = array.getJSONObject(i);

  String key = c.getString("key");
  String value = c.getString("value");
  a.append(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:-

```
String result="[{"key":0,"value":"--Any--"},{"key":61,"value":"Accounting"},{"key":81,"value":"Aerospace & Defense"},{"key":72,"value":"Automotive"},{"key":83,"value":"Banking"},{"key":84,"value":"Biotech"},{"key":85,"value":"Construction"},{"key":86,"value":"Customer Service"},{"key":87,"value":"Education"},{"key":82,"value":"Energy"},{"key":70,"value":"Finance"},{"key":193,"value":"Government"},{"key":194,"value":"Healthcare"},{"key":71,"value":"Insurance"},{"key":73,"value":"Legal"},{"key":62,"value":"Management"},{"key":63,"value":"Manufacturing"},{"key":64,"value":"Marketing\/Advertising"},{"key":77,"value":"Media - Journalism"},{"key":74,"value":"Pharmaceutical"},{"key":75,"value":"Real Estate"},{"key":76,"value":"Research"},{"key":65,"value":"Restaurant"},{"key":66,"value":"Retail"},{"key":67,"value":"Sales"},{"key":78,"value":"Science"},{"key":68,"value":"Telecommunications"},{"key":79,"value":"Training"},{"key":69,"value":"Transportation"},{"key":80,"value":"Utilities"}]";
JSONArray menuObject = new JSONArray(result);
String app;
for (int i = 0; i<menuObject.length(); i++) {
{
 app=menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("value").toString();
 a.append(app); // a is my TextView
}
```